# how to add a column to existing array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a (1000,2) array and I was wondering how you can add a (1000,1) array without looping. What's the pythonic way to do this in numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`numpy.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html).

```
a = np.zeros((1000,2))
b = np.zeros((1000,1))
c = np.hstack((a,b))
```